# Adding type signature causes compile error

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In Haskell I can define a function like this:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo n = n + 1
```

If I want to be anal, I can add a type signature to the last line like this:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo n = n + 1 :: Int
```

I can also define a function `bar` in terms of a type class like this:

```
class Rel a b where
  aToB :: a -> b

bar :: (Rel a b) => a -> b
bar a = aToB a
```

However if I add a type signature to the implementation of `bar` (a benign change, or so I thought), I get a compile error.

```
bar :: (Rel a b) => a -> b
bar a = aToB a :: b
```

And here's the error:

```
Could not deduce (Rel a b1) arising from a use of `aToB'
from the context (Rel a b)
  bound by the type signature for bar :: Rel a b => a -> b
  at q.hs:79:1-23
Possible fix:
  add (Rel a b1) to the context of
    an expression type signature: b1
    or the type signature for bar :: Rel a b => a -> b
In the expression: aToB val :: b
In an equation for `bar': bar val = aToB val :: b
```

I think the error means that the compiler isn't convinced that the `b` in the implementation of `bar` is the same as the `b` in the type signature of `bar`.  However, I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Why do I get this compile error when I add a type signature to my function implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the scope of type variables.  When you write

```
bar :: (Rel a b) => a -> b
bar a = aToB a :: b
```

The first line (the type declaration for `bar`) has its own scope for type variables, and on the second line it sees the `:: b` as a different b from the `Rel a b`.

If you enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and declare your type as

```
bar :: forall a b. (Rel a b) => a -> b
```

Then the `b`'s scope extends over the definition of `bar`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a reason that extension couldn't just be always enabled?  Or is it like multi-param type classes: clearly a good idea, but just not in the core language?

Comment: It's often a good idea but it isn't Haskel98, so it's an extension.  I haven't run into instances where it's a problem to have it enabled personally, but others may be able to elaborate on it more.

Comment: I've asked this a few times before. To my current understanding it was just an oversight in Haskell98 and there's no downside.

Answer (score 6):

You actually need a language extension and a bit of extra syntax to make the two `b` type variables be the same:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
bar :: forall a b . (Rel a b) => a -> b
bar a = aToB a :: b
```

The `forall` is essentially saying "`a` and `b` should be in scope for the whole definition", and `ScopedTypeVariables` is needed to be allowed to use this syntax.

I guess this is really a historic wart in the design of the language.